# Antonym of "context"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

If I wanted to analyse a piece of art "contextually" I would be using information that isn't actually part of the piece of art to analyse it.

What is the word for what is actually *inside* the piece of art?

Comment: Carbon ink and paper, or dried colored oils and canvas, mostly. Some pieces of art, like dances, don't have insides to be in.

Comment: Why would a term like "the piece of art" (which you use) be inappropriate here? After all, context addresses what isn't part of the piece of art, so "the piece of art" itself would be one opposite.

Comment: Are you asking about its soul?

Comment: Do you think that there is always an antonym for a description?  Obviously there isn't:  words like 'red', 'triangular' and 'murderous' do not, for different reasons, have antonyms.  There are many different approaches to the critical analysis of works of art, some of which are opposed to each other.  You can look at a painting from an historical point of view, and you can look at it purely aesthetically, or you can do both at the same time.  You can look at from a structuralist, post structuralist or even marxist point of view.  These are different but not opposites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In isolation*. To analyse a work of art in isolation is to analyse it alone, without consideration of anything outside of the artwork itself.

*Out of context* is related, but to me it can imply that the artwork has been deliberately removed from its context, whether in terms of the analysis or of the setting in which the analyst encounters it.

Comment: With respect to Lambie, this meets the OP's needs much more precisely, I think.

Comment: "Without context" is sort of a middle ground

Comment: @dbmag9 Why bother mentioning me then??

Comment: @Lambie I think when I commented I'd just read your answer, and obviously you put lots of work into writing it and finding the references. No subtext intended!

Answer (score 7):

What is inside a work of art are its contents....either representations or physical stuff like paint or marble.

What is outside of it, is extrinsic (as opposed to intrinsic) and part of the context in which it is produced!

as in this text:

1)

> However, attempting to draw out values from that experience and thus
> construct an extrinsic framework in which to understand and
> objectively judge art, as Greenberg does, ultimately makes his own
> responses interested (as his judgements are constantly related to a
> set of criteria which are pre-formulated)

[extrinsic to a work of art](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Signals-and-noise%3A-art%2C-literature-and-the-Otty/770c346274c70620e90885353194844145c5d624?p2df)

2)

> Students will therefore demonstrate an awareness of the appropriate
> uses of different kinds of information in the construction of a
> critical text, including information intrinsic and extrinsic to the
> art work or works.

[extrinsic to the art work](https://sites.newpaltz.edu/ncate/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/04/ARE200.pdf)

3)

> The arts will no longer attempt to communicate a conceptual message
> that can be abstracted from the work: they will not seek to represent,
> but rather will attempt to eliminate anything extrinsic to the
> art-work and thus to present “art” as such.

[extrinsic to the art-work](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/3454/Otty2008.pdf?sequence=3)

Enough, right?

Intrinsic:

Is the quality of art intrinsic to the artwork, or extrinsic?  How have different contexts elevated some art works from the past, and diminished others?

[intrinsic](https://community.macmillanlearning.com/t5/bits-blog/when-is-a-banana-just-a-banana/ba-p/5354)

Merriam-Webster

Definition of extrinsic
1a: not forming part of or belonging to a thing : EXTRANEOUS
b: originating from or on the outside
especially : originating outside a part and acting upon the part as a whole
extrinsic muscles of the tongue
2: EXTERNAL

Comment: Could you explain this answer a bit more, please?  I think the 'intrinsic'/'extrinsic' distinction might be along the right lines.  But I cannot tell whether you are saying that the antonym of 'contextually' would be 'intrinsically' or that it would be 'extrinsically'.  I assume you must intend 'contextually' to be the antonym, I get the impression that you are suggesting 'extrinsically'.

Comment: inside the piece of art, intrinsically; outside of it, extrinsically. Very simple really.

Comment: So to explicitly say what Lambie won't: intrinsic refers to the work of art without the surrounding context. So, it is the antonym of the ("extrinsic") context that the art is situated in.

Comment: @Lambie No, it isn't as simple as that.  The meaning of these natural antonyms is not my problem.  Maybe we have different understandings of what a 'contextual' analysis/appreciation is.  On one understanding, it would mean that I am interpreting a work from the past, taking account of its historical setting.  The opposite of that would be to take no account of its historical setting.  So some US high court judges think that the US constitution should take account only of the literal meaning of the constitution, while others think the historical context should be taken into account.

Comment: @ Lambie  <continued> this latter sort of interpretation would would be regarded as 'contextual'.  The obvious opposite to that would be 'literal' or 'literalistic'.  Are you saying that 'extrinsic' is the opposite of or the same as 'contextual'?

Comment: @Tuffy Art and history are not the same thing. That said, regardless of the field of endeavor, extrinsic is outside the thing or object or field and intrinsic is inside the thing or object or field.

Comment: @ Lambie  So be it.  My main response to the OP is that not every adjective has to have an antonym, that the terminology of criticism is a very good example of a field where alternative perspectives do not have antonyms.

Comment: @Tuffy The question was badly posed. Obviously, the word context has no "antonym" per se.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *contextually* is *[acontextually](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acontextual)*, where *acontextual* means "not relating to or determined by a particular context".

Comment: Downvoters - can you please leave some feedback rather than just voting down?

Answer (score 0):

#### Subject matter

noun

> the topic dealt with or the subject represented in a debate, exposition, or work of art.

[[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subject_matter)

Comment: antonym is the opposite, subject matter is a synonym.

Comment: Subject matter is to context, as in is to out.  No amount of wordiness, either, can alter this fact.

Comment: Subject matter is what a work is **about**, not what's **in** it, in the way that the OP has in mind; many forms of art don't have subject matter.

Comment: @jsw29 Again, there is no in/out of any kind to do with a piece of art, or a story.  And, a piece of art can't be fully appreciated, analyzed, or whatever, if at all without the context.  No man, painting, etc, is an island.

Comment: In other words, by definition, to remove the outside is to render the inside meaningless.  Up is meaningless without down.  Say, what truer painting then to remove also all observers?  This is the reason that the internet is just the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Aesthetics.

> But the lack of information accompanying each artwork means it is perfect for the "I know what I like" brigade. Critics and punters alike are forced to put their reputations on the line and make *purely aesthetic judgments*.

[The pleasure of art without context](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/artblog/2008/jun/09/thepleasureofartwithoutco)

Comment: No, "aesthetics" is more like "beauty" or "form". It's *one aspect* of a piece of art. Although, I'm not an artist so IDK if it has a more technical meaning in an art context.

Comment: @wjandrea Aesthetic is form without meaning. As meaning can only exist within a context, without context you only have aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be ["per se:"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per%20se)

> by, of, or in itself or oneself or themselves : as such : INTRINSICALLY

(Merriam-Webster)

I most often see "per se" used to set up an immediate contrast between something's intrinsic properties and the broader context, e.g. "The painting doesn't reveal the artist's political views per se, but when placed among the other paintings in the exhibition, it clearly fits into a pattern." I think you could use "per se" without this kind of contrast, but it doesn't feel as natural to me. This may just be due to a lack of imagination on my part in coming up with more example uses, though.